# What does target location symbol on the map indicates in GTA SA?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

The marker which indicates the location of target on map.The marker is sometimes triangle in shape and sometime inverted triangle and sometimes square .What does these changes indicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker indicates the altitude with respect to your location and the target location.If triangle is reverted that means you are at more altitude than target else you are below the target.If the shape is square that means you and target are at same altitude level.

Answer (score 1):

The direction at which the triangle is pointing indicates the position of the target relative to you and see level. If the tip of the triangle is pointing down, that means you are above the target, if the tip is pointing up, then you are bellow the target. The square is the "normal" state, which indicates that you too are on the same level.